# Define number of rows and columns that have no 0 (zeros) in 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am printing out 2D array. I use a loop to scan one column for zeros and walking in circles on how to create a loop for every column and row.

I cannot use vector -- must be something simple, like loops , do , while (first semester level C++).

Any suggestions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <iomanip>


using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n, m;

    
    // User enters number of rows and colums
    
    
    cout << "Enter number of rows: " << "    ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Enter number of columns: " << " ";

    cin >> m;
     
    int r1 = 0;
    int c1 = 0;
    int temp = 0;


    // Initialize 2d array

    int **arr = new int *[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        arr[i] = new int[m];


    // Generate random numbers to fill an array

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)

        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            arr[i][j] = (rand() % 9);



    //Print out  2D array

    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m;  j++)
            cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }

    

    // Loop to compare first column values if they are not equal to zero

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    
        // For each value in column that is not equal to zero,  "temp" variable is adding 1

        if (*arr[i] != 0)   temp++;


        if (n == temp) c1++;

        // missing part here
        // probably the loop 
        // for remaining colums
        // and all of the rows

        //cannot use vector

    cout << "Number of rows without zero is:" << "     " << r1<< endl;
    cout << "Number of cols without zero is:" << "     " << c1 << endl;
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have loops that print out each member of the array

```
for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < m;  j++)
        cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

You just need the same to check for zeros

```
for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
{
    if (arr[i][0] == 0)
        count1++;          // count zeros in first column
    for (int j = 0; j < m;  j++)
        if (arr[i][j] == 0)
            count2++;      // count all zeros
}
```

I think maybe you were overthinking this problem

**EDIT**

OK maybe I misunderstood the problem, the question is not very clear. The title says that you want to find the number of columns with no zeros. Here's how you would do that.

```
for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
{
    bool found_zero = false;   // no zeros found so far
    for (int j = 0; j < m;  j++)
    {
        if (arr[i][j] == 0)
        {
            found_zero = true; // found a zero
            break;             // quit loop early
        }
    }
    if (!found_zero)
        count++;               // count columns with no zeros
}
```

Once you've found a zero you can quit the loop, since finding more zeros would make no difference.

I call these kind of loop *existential* loops, since you are checking if something does or does not exist (like a zero) over a range of values. They often confuse newbies, but once you've seen how to do them they become very easy. The simplest way to implement them is to add a `bool` variable which you check at the end of the loop.

Comment: Thank you for the columns , it works , but the problem is find the number of columns and rows. I used the same method to count rows , by changing arr[i][j] to arr[j][i] and it works only if array has even (m x n) (ex. 4 rows and 4 columns). If i try to run uneven number of rows and colums  Ex. 1 row and 12 colums the program stops. Or i get miscalculations if rows and cols are 6x8. How to fix that?

Comment: @Mikelkenneth  You need to do more than swap `i` for `j`, you also have to swap `m` and `n`. Basically the inner loop becomes the outer one, and vice versa.